# How do I establish a connection to my local database when accessing my website from a different computer?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to host a website on my raspberry pi that I can access from other computers on the same network. The website connects to a local database (that is hosted on the same raspberry pi) grabs some data, converts the output to a json file that then use google's visualization API to draw a line graph. Everything works fine on my raspberry pi.... but when I try to access the webpage from a different computer on the same network I get "Connect failedAccess denied for user 'root'@'localhost'" When trying to access the webpage I'm literally just typing in the IP address of the raspberry pi.

I'm using php 7.0.33-0+deb9u3, Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian).

I've searched around and haven't really been able to find an answer... I could also just be trying to search for the wrong information.

Here is the code that I use to connect to the database on my raspberry pi

```
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';                                                                                                     
$pass = '';
$dbname = 'CDMA_STATUS';
$local_db = new mysqli($server,$user,$pass,$dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connect failed".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```

Comment: The error seems like you're trying to access to DB on pi3 from your own local webserver. You can try to debug by echo the guess IP and server IP to check.

Comment: Maybe a web service of some kind is what you need?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys... it turns out it was a permissions issue with root. I created a user in my MariaDB with a password with all permissions and that worked.